# How to get the name of the action in an after_action filter for ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

In the class below, how do I get the current action name (i.e. `email_confirmation`, `password_reset`) in side the `after_action` callback `add_mandril_headers`?

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  after_action :add_mandril_headers

  def email_confirmation(user)
    mail(..)
  end

  def password_reset(user)
    mail(..)
  end

private

  # how to get the action name? 
  def add_mandrill_headers
    headers['X-MC-Tags'] = [mailer_name, action_name].join('_');
  end
end
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out `action_name` returns the current mailer action name. I tried it based on the fact that `ActionController` has a similar method.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @HarishShetty!

As you mentioned, the `action_name` is good for all Controllers, as it is inherited from `ApplicationController`.

For example, I was using [public_activity](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity) and wanted some simplification in my controllers:

```
class SiteDetailsController < ApplicationController

  after_action :track_activity, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]

  # ...

  private

  def track_activity
    @site_detail.create_activity action_name, owner: current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: Yep, thats why I said `I tried it based on the fact that ActionController has a similar method.`