# Rails 3.2 can't dry up this Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I need an instance variable named @template_name in about 15 action mailer methods in my UserMailer for marketing purposes. I don't want to go around dropping stuff like:

```
@template_name  = __callee__
```

In all my methods, or dropping strings in the views, i'd like to make this as DRY as possible.  Creating a callback that can access the method name and not itself seems challenging, ie this return "do_thing" regardless of what method it fires from.

```
before_action :do_thing
def do_thing
  __callee__ # old way was __method__ 
end
```

Any recommendations are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822926/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-action-in-an-after-action-filter-for-actionmailer) post.

If I'm understanding it correctly, you could simply do the following:

**Rails > 4**

```
before_action { @template_name = action_name }
```

**Rails < 4**

```
  include AbstractController::Callbacks
  before_action { @template_name = action_name }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Edited your answer for < Rails 4 solution. Thanks!!!